# incompatible types in assignment of `float' to `char[3]'

Tags: c

trying to figure out what is going on here. I'm just learning C, so go easy on me. :P I was assigned to create a unit converter from centimeters to inches. I've got it. Now I want to spice it up a little by creating options. My compiler isn't enjoying what I have. this is the first few lines....

```
main(void)   

{
float centimeter;
char cnv[3];
float entry;
float oz;
float lb;
float cm;
float lb1;
centimeter=2.54;
lb1=2.2;



printf("Hello. Please type exactly, the type of conversion you would like to do.\n\n1. cm to in\n\n2. lb to kg\n");
scanf("%3c",&cnv);


    if (strcmp(cnv=cm));
        {
        printf("Please enter your length in centimeters:\n");
        scanf("%f",&entry);
        printf("with %.0f centimeters in length, that converts to %.2f inches.",entry,entry/centimeter);
        }

    if (strcmp(cnv=lb));
        {
        printf("Please enter your weight in pounds:\n");
        scanf("%f",&entry);
        printf("with %.0f Pound(s) of weight, that converts to %.2f Kilogram(s).",entry,entry/lb1);
        }


}
```

and it's giving me the error in the title. How can I fix this?

Comment: What exact error is it giving you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The '=' operator is used for assigning values not comparison. You should use '==' for comparisons.
2. The values that you are of different types. You should convert one of the variables to the other type to compare.
3. Strings must be compared with some string comparison function like strcmp() as you have done, but strcmp() is a function and therefore the you should pass the parameters in with a comma separating them.
4. As an aside strcmp() returns 0 when the strings that you pass in are equivalent, so using a syntax more like this would be appropriate:  `if(!strcmp(cnv, cm))` or  `if(strcmp(cnv, cm) == 0)`
5. If I might take a guess what you really were looking to do was something like: `if(strcmp(cnv, "cm") == 0)` cm is a name of a variable whereas "cm" is a zero terminated string with the characters 'c' and 'm'
6. The next thing that you will need to worry about is reading in the 3 characters from scanf, because if the input was "cm" and the user pressed enter to enter the text. The program scanned 3 characters one of which was the newline character '\n'. So when you go to do the strcmp() the program will compare each character up till it reaches a byte that has been zeroed out. With just 3 characters being read I am not sure if the string you are capturing is zero terminated, but I am sure that the string could contain a '\n' which would throw the results of strcmp() way off.

Answer (score 3):

1) You're confusing = (assignment) with == (test for equality)

2) You can't compare a numeric value directly to a character array. You need to convert one or the other to a type which can be compared -- convert the number to string, if your using `strcmp()` (and understand how that function returns its results, which aren't what you've assumed here), or convert the string to a numeric type and compare that way.

Answer (score 0):

The`strcmp` syntax is not correct. For more about string compare function please check this link
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm